# Rosserial Arduino control by keyboard

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wonder use keyboard to control My arduino for making a little car.

So I use the package "[ros-keyboard](https://github.com/lrse/ros-keyboard)" and write a node myself([click me to github](https://github.com/AlysonQ/slam_car/blob/master/slam_car.ino)).

And it seems that two packages' data types are different, even the arduino recive topic message "/keyboard/keydown", there is nothing happen when I push buttom on the keyboard.

Do I miss something ?  thanks!! > <

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224965/rosserial-arduino-control-by-keyboard/) by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The publisher is sending messages with the message type `keyboard/Key`, but your subscriber is subscribing to message with the type `std_msgs/Empty`. Since these message types don't match, the subscriber will discard any messages it receives.

You're also reading data from the serial line with the `Serial` class in Arduino, and trying to use rosserial at the same time. Since both are trying to use the serial line, there will be a conflict, and rosserial probably will not work. The keypress data you want should be in the `keyboard/Key` message, so you don't need to do Serial.read().

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-01-27**:
Thanks for your response.I am planning to modify arduino code to subscribe to keyboard/Key.